# How to return oracle output parameters from a stored procedure in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am having serious issues trying to get the data back from the SP. I was trying to do it like this:

```
OracleCommand ora_cmd = new OracleCommand("a6r1.PR_ABC_P_ALTA_TARJETA_PAYWARE", ora_conn);
                    ora_cmd.BindByName = true;
                    ora_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    int success= new int();

                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Param_Issuer", OracleDbType.Varchar2, issuer, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Ln_Param_Valid_Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2, DropDownListProducto.SelectedValue.ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Ln_Param_Total", OracleDbType.Int32, parsed, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Param_User", OracleDbType.Varchar2, user, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Encrypted_Password", OracleDbType.Varchar2, pass, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Exito", OracleDbType.Int32, success, ParameterDirection.Output);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Error", OracleDbType.Varchar2, errorMessage, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

But it is not returning anything to the variables sucess or errorMessage. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way? It works fine when executed directly on Oracle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems you cannot use existing variable as output parameter, try this way instead

```
ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Exito", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (ora_cmd.Parameters["Lc_Exito"].value == 0)
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I did not expect oracle parameters to be so specific versus sql's. Than you very much.

Comment: `if (ora_cmd.Parameters["Lc_Exito"]).value == 0)` has an extra bracket in it.  Do you mean `if (ora_cmd.Parameters["Lc_Exito"].value == 0)`?

Answer (score 9):

I have not found anywhere where it documents the whole process in one place, so after hitting my head against the wall and banging it out, here is my version of what I came up with, using one of the output parameters from the OP's code:

```
OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();
param = ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Exito", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);  // can assign the direction within the parameter declaration
param.Size = 25;  // failed for me if I did not have this - should be the same as the DB field, if exporting a value from the database

ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

int myLc_ExitoValue = int.Parse(param.Value);  // might not need to parse, and might need a .ToString() on param.Value if you do - I was using strings so not sure about OP's exact case
```

Then the stored procedure needs to be set up to accept the `OUT` parameter and you must assign to it in the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure PR_ABC_P_ALTA_TARJETA_PAYWARE(Lc_Exito OUT number)
  as
  begin
    Lc_Exito := 123;
  end;
 /
```

Obviously this leaves out all the other parameters that were being sent in and the other "out" parameters - wanted to simplify it.  But this shows how everything gets set up, from before, during, and after the call to the stored procedure in the C#, and how to set the `OUT` parameter, and get the value out, of the stored procedure.

Comment: I would like to highlight that the "Size" property is very important for the string output parameters, as the inline comment in the code indicates.