# Executing Oracle Procedure with out parameters

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I need help calling a stored procedure in an Oracle DB that has 2 out parameters. I haven't used out parameters before and I'm also not very familar with Oracle. I am getting the following error when calling the query from a .net webpage:

> "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

I was given the instructions below on how to update a few fields using an existing procedure:

```
In the P_API_BO_Vehicle package:
procedure ChangeLastMileage(pVehicleID T_FM_VEHICLE.F_VEH_ID%type,
                            pMileage T_FM_VEHICLE.F_VEH_LAST_MILE%type,
                            pDate T_FM_VEHICLE.F_VEH_LAST_DATE%type,
                            pErrorCode out binary_integer,
                            pErrorInfo out TErrorInfo);
```

So I have tried the following query string:

```
VAR pErrorCode binary_integer 
VAR pErrorInfo TErrorInfo 
EXEC P_API_BO_Vehicle.ChangeLastMileage(18391, 20000, '2014-04-28', pErrorCode, pErrorInfo);
```

But it gives the error above. Am I doing something wrong regarding passing in the "Out" parameters?

Comment: `VAR` don't support user defined Data-types. And it is a `SQL*Plus` command.

Comment: It was an attempt (guess) based off a different answer I read here on SO. What should I do instead?

Comment: using `Parameters.add("<Parmetername>",<pre defiined datatype>)` and specify the parameters `direction`. [This SO answer should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247921/how-to-return-oracle-output-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-net). Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work, thought I would give the answer encase anyone is having a similar problem.

```
declare
  pDate date; 
  pErrorCode binary_integer;
  pErrorInfo varchar2(500); 
begin 
  pDate := to_date('2014-04-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 
  P_API_BO_Vehicle.ChangeLastMileage(18391, 20000, pDate, pErrorCode, pErrorInfo); 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be PL/SQL begin .. end block could help you

```
declare
    pErrorCode binary_integer;
    pErrorInfo TErrorInfo;
begin
  P_API_BO_Vehicle.ChangeLastMileage(18391, 20000, '2014-04-28', pErrorCode, pErrorInfo);
end;
/
```

or you trying to call this from C# enviroment?