# Issue in fetching data from SP (Oracle Database)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

As I am new to this, I am facing some issue in executing stored procedure in oracle DB. Here is the SP which gives record as output parameter which is of type %rowtype and l_serno as input parameter which is of type Number.

```
Create OR Replace procedure get_product(l_serno in product.serno%type,record out product%rowtype)
is

begin

select * into record from product where serno=l_serno;

end get_product;
```

Using C#, I am trying to fetch the data from the SP and show it on the gridview.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("get_product", Conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Conn.Open();
                OracleParameter input = cmd.Parameters.Add("V_SERNO", OracleType.Number);
                OracleParameter output = cmd.Parameters.Add("ITEMS_CURSOR", OracleType.Cursor);
                input.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                output.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                input.Value = 2;
                OracleDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(rd);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Conn.Close();
```

Here I am getting error as

ORA-06550: line 1, column 24:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_PRODUCT'

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

Please let me know what is the wrong I am doing here.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Instead of `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;`, have you tried `ParameterDirection.Output;`?;

Comment: Hi Hassan Nisar, Thanks for your reply. I tried with ParameterDirection.Output as well. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Cross check the `OracleType` you mentioned in the parameters. Also check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247921/how-to-return-oracle-output-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-net) as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As you suggested, i changed the "l_serno in product.serno%type" to "l_serno number", this did a trick and started working.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure has this signature:

```
(l_serno in product.serno%type,record out product%rowtype)
```

But in your C# code you specify this:

```
 OracleParameter output = cmd.Parameters.Add("ITEMS_CURSOR", OracleType.Cursor);
```

A cursor is a pointer to a result set and is different from a variable.  You could change your C# code: define a class whose attributes match the projection of the PRODUCT table.  Alternatively, change the stored procedure to use a ref cursor.

The second approach is probably less work (not least because you can get us to do it for you)

```
create or replace procedure get_product
       (l_serno in product.serno%type,
            record out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
     open record for  
            select * from product
             where serno=l_serno; 
end get_product;
```

Comment: Hi APC, thanks for your reply. As suggested by you, i tried changing the stored procedure out parameter to cursor. I was getting the same error. Then i changed "l_serno in product.serno%type" to "l_serno number", this did a trick and started working